# AWS RDS allocated_storage size

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I'm creating AWS RDS instance to migrate existing on-prem oracle database to AWS Rds instance.

Existing On-prem oracle database is appox 700GB.

I've two queries

1. what allocate storage size should i use for RDS oracle database instance,
   should it be equal or greater then on-prem oracle database?
2. which instance type should be suitable for size of database?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using S3 import method with Data Pump, you would need sufficient space to download the backup file to RDS Oracle instance + restore the same, so a little more than double should be a good option to create with(~1.5TB). If you are using some other method where you don't need the backup file on RDS, you can try provisioning around 800 GB initially.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html#Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPump

2. It depends on your workload, and you might need to look at current Oracle AWR reports to analyze suitable CPU and RAM requirements. Nevertheless, you can start with something which you feel should suffice, and scale up or down as needed.